# Ten thousand and first prime checker takes a very long time

Tags: java, performance, primes, programming-challenge

I am attempting problem 7 on Project Euler.  I have come up with this solution which works fine for finding smaller nth prime numbers, but really lags when it comes to higher nth prime numbers.  I am not quite sure where to start to make it more efficient.

```
public class TenThousandFirstPrime {

    public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
        if(num % 2 == 0) return false;
        for(int i = 3; i < Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num)); i += 2) {
            if(num % i == 0) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 2;  
        int i = 3;
        while(count <= 10001) {
            if(isPrime(i)) {
                i += 2;
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The solution only took a couple of minutes and I didn't expect it to be as slow as it is...

Comment: Re. how to make it faster, that's probably been explained in answers to some of the [other questions about prime numbers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes).

Comment: Use solutions to previously solved problems to solve new problems. Suppose you want to know if 12347 is prime. If you have already computed the prime numbers less than or equal to root 12347, then you only need to check whether 12347 is divisible by each of them, not all the numbers up to the root.

Comment: Skipping every other number is smart. You could be smarter by starting i at 12, increasing by 6 each time, and then checking i-1 and i-5 for primeness in the loop. Clearly i, i-2, i-3 and i-4 are divisible by either 2 or 3.

Comment: "I didn't expect it to be as slow as it is" -- The **infinite loop** identified in 200_success' answer and [Jamal's comment](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45115/ten-thousand-and-first-prime-checker-takes-a-very-long-time#comment78572_45123) explains why it's slower than slow (i.e. endless).

Comment: I've noticed that you use `i += 2;`, probably because you've eliminated all multiples of 2 from the possible prime numbers. Why only for 2? Why not take that to its logical conclusion, and eliminate all multiples of every prime number you find? That's what the Sieve of Eratosthenes does - you should look into that if you want a faster prime number generator.

Comment: The Project Euler website lays out in great detail a fast solution to this problem as soon as you solve the problem the first time...  (just fyi)

Comment: Here's something I posted several years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1134851/109122.  It actually calculate Euler's Totient values (PHI), but as a side effect, it finds all of the primes up to some N quite fast.  It's based on a wheeled Sieve of Eratosthenes and takes 3 secs to get to 1 million, and that's doing all of the extra work for the Totients.  Take them out and it would be much faster.

Comment: @RedAlert Thank you, I ended up using the Sieve of Eratosthenes and it did it in just over 15 milliseconds.

Answer (score 6):

The square root calculation could just be done before the loop.  Since this value does not change within the function, it doesn't need to be recalculated each time through the loop.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) return false;

    int squareRoot = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
    for (int i = 3; i < squareRoot; i += 2) {
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6093537/49942) suggest your answer is correct: that the repeated `sqrt` isn't optimized away by the JVM.

Answer (score 5):

Your code does not work. Your `main()` has an infinite loop.

Trial division is a simple way to test whether a single number is prime. However, to test many numbers, you want to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

You `isPrime()` reports that 1 is prime and 2 is not. That might be acceptable if you take care to never call it with those parameters and **document those special cases in JavaDoc.**

Comment: 1. I don't see the infinite loop in `main`?  2. The Sieve of Eratosthenes would work well here, but there's the question of knowing in advance how large to make your table of candidates.  Also it would require O(n) memory instead of O(1) as for trial division.  3. That's a good point about `isPrime`, but you'll notice that in fact it is only ever called with `num >= 3`.

Comment: @NateEldredge: `count` is only incremented if `isPrime()` returns true.  Once the `while` loop gets a non-prime number (4 being the first one), the `if` will be skipped, so `count` will not increment.

Comment: @Jamal Actually, `i` will get stuck at 9.

Comment: @NateEldredge 2. The _n_ th prime is approximately [_n_ ln _n_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Number_of_prime_numbers_below_a_given_number); it turns out that for 10000, this estimate is about 12% too low, but still it's a useful guide.  In my opinion, using 100 kB for the sieve is a worthwhile expense. 3. Avoiding the erroneous cases of `isPrime()` is fine, but my point is that failure to document those cases is poor practice.

Comment: Nate, at the point where you have so many primes that the memory matters, you would use consecutive sieves, for example make a sieve for the primes from 1 to 1 million, another for primes from 1 million to 2 millions, and so on, to keep memory use under control.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need `<=` in isPrime's for loop: because otherwise you'll decide that 25 is prime.

Comment: Moreover, you probably want to replace `floor` with `ceil`; due to the limited precision of floating point, `Math.sqrt(25)` could return `4.99999996` or something similar.

Comment: @NateEldredge [This document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double)) says, "the result is the double value closest to the true mathematical square root of the argument value" ... so perhaps the result is exact (an integer value) if the argument is a perfect square.

Comment: Ok, true, assuming that your floating point implementation is able to represent small integers exactly (which most are).

Answer (score 0):

Unless your compiler is quite clever, it will calculate Math.floor (Math.sqrt (num)) on every single iteration of the loop, which will probably take three times longer than the rest of the operations.

"i < Math.floor (Math.sqrt (num))" is really, really bad. It makes your code think that squares of primes are prime (for example 9, 25, 49), but also products of consecutive twin primes, like 15 = 3x5, 35 = 5x7, 143 = 11x13 and so on.

As mentioned, the loop in main stops making progress when it reaches the first non-prime. I would write the loop in the most straightforward way:

```
for (int i = 3; ; i += 2)
{
    if (isPrime (i))
    {
        // Whatever you want to do with primes
    }
}
```

And in general, I wouldn't put lots of code into main (). main () should in my opinion process any parameters, then call code doing the work.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the i+=2 should be outside the if statement, otherwise it gets stuck on the first non prime number:

```
   i += 2;
   if(isPrime(i)) {
       count++;
   }
```

Moving the sqrt calculation outside is one option, another one is to test for the square value like this because a multiplication is not as expensive as the square root calculation:

```
for(int i = 3; i*i < num ; i+=2)
```

For testing why it is slow start with printing out the result of every while iteration, so you can if it just gets slower with larger numbers or if it gets stuck somewhere.

You could also try to work with BigInteger and another algorithm, this one takes around 5 seconds on my old PC and it should work fine with larger numbers too.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;

public class Euler7
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(new Date());
        BigInteger primesProduct = BigInteger.valueOf(2*3);
        BigInteger primesFound = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        BigInteger testForPrime = BigInteger.valueOf(3);
        BigInteger limit = BigInteger.valueOf(10001);
        while(primesFound.compareTo(limit)<0)
        {
            testForPrime = testForPrime.add(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
            if(((primesProduct.gcd(testForPrime)).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE))==0)
            {
                primesProduct = primesProduct.multiply(testForPrime);
                primesFound = primesFound.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(new Date());
        System.out.println("found: "+testForPrime);
    }
}
```